# How do I catch unhandled exceptions with rollbar-browser?

Tags: javascript, webpack, rollbar, rollbar-browser

I have a fairly simple Webpack configuration and have added `rollbar-browser` to my solution. In my entry file, I have the following:

```
import rollbar from 'rollbar-browser';
import home from './containers/home';

const rollbarConfig = {
  accessToken: ROLLBAR_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  captureUncaught: true,
  captureUnhandledRejections: true,
  payload: {
    environment: ENVIRONMENT,
  },
  endpoint: 'https://api.rollbar.com/api/1/',
};

const Rollbar = rollbar.init(rollbarConfig);

window.Rollbar = Rollbar;
throw new Error('I will be handled. Others, maybe not...');
```

The exception above is handled. However, if I throw an exception anywhere else in the application (`home`, for example), then the exception is ignored.

For the sake of completeness, `home` is simply this:

```
export default class HomeContainer {
    constructor() {
        throw new Error('Why am I not caught?');
    }
}
```

How can I get Rollbar to handle all unhandled exceptions?

Comment: Where are you instantiating `HomeContainer`?

Comment: It's actually the controller for an angular 1.5 component. It doesn't do anything other than this, yet. The exception is thrown in the browser, though.

Comment: Rollbar is also available as a global object at this point, too.

Comment: Hey Chris, it looks like you already were in touch w/ Rollbar support, but if you're continuing to have issues with this, please follow-up with us so we can keep on troubleshooting it.

Comment: Hey chris, in their documentation they're saying that `captureUnhandledRejections` is used for Promises, which I am trying to solve. Would you be so kind and update/answer your own question with your findings?